# Конвертирование строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, url, qiwi

пишу скрипт под API Qiwi.
При отправке запроса, в случае, если количество выплат не уместилось в размер запрошенной информации (от 1 до 50), необходимо отправить новый запрос с определенными параметрами.

Вот запрос:

```
"https://edge.qiwi.com/payment-history/v2/persons/79112223344/payments?rows=50&nextTxnId=9103121&nextTxnDate=2017-05-11T12%3A35%3A23%2B03%3A00"
```

Из предыдущего запроса я получил json, из которого вытащил значения:

```
next_txn_date: 2018-12-24T23:28:05+03:00
next_txn_id:  14552442122
```

Как мне привести next_txn_date к виду, который находится в запросе. Как я понял, необходимо спецсимволы конвертировать

[Документация](https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#payments_list)

Отправляю запросы библиотекой requests.

Вот какая ошибка приходит при отправке запроса

```
{'serviceName': 'payment-history', 'errorCode': 'validation.error', 'description': 'Validation error', 'userMessage': 'Validation error', 'dateTime': '2018-12-26T11:29:51.578+03:00', 'traceId': '0e1200e77a2877d9', 'cause': {'nextTxnDate': ['Wrong date format']}}
```

Код:

```
header = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   "Authorization": "Bearer " + token}
root_url = "https://edge.qiwi.com/"
def get_payment_list(self):
    url = root_url + "payment-history/v2/persons/" + login + "/payments?rows=1"
    json_text = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()
    print(json_text)
    while True:
        try:
            next_txn_id = json_text["nextTxnId"]
            next_txn_date = json_text["nextTxnDate"]
            if((next_txn_id is not None) and (next_txn_date is not None)):
                print("next_txn_date", next_txn_date)
                print("next_txn_id ", next_txn_id)
                next_url = root_url + "payment-history/v2/persons/" + login + "/payments?rows=1&nextTxnId=" + str(next_txn_id) +"&nextTxnDate=" + next_txn_date
                json_text = requests.get(next_url, headers=self.header).json()
                print(json_text)
            else:
                break
        except KeyError:
            print("Превышение лимита запросов (100). Блокировка на 5 минут")
            time.sleep(301)
```

Json, от первого запроса:

```
{'data': [{'txnId': 14552452204, 'personId': 79822304501, 'date': '2018-12-24T23:31:05+03:00', 'errorCode': 0, 'error': None, 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'type': 'OUT', 'statusText': 'Success', 'trmTxnId': '992754691630', 'account': '+79295320477', 'sum': {'amount': 12730, 'currency': 643}, 'commission': {'amount': 0, 'currency': 643}, 'total': {'amount': 12730, 'currency': 643}, 'provider': {'id': 99, 'shortName': 'Перевод на QIWI Кошелек', 'longName': 'Доставляется мгновенно', 'logoUrl': 'https://static.qiwi.com/img/providers/logoBig/99_l.png', 'description': None, 'keys': 'пополнить, перевести, qiwi, кошелек, оплатить, онлайн, оплата, счет, способ, услуга,перевести', 'siteUrl': 'http://www.qiwi.com', 'extras': [{'key': 'ceo_description', 'value': 'Пополнение QIWI Кошелька банковской картой без комисии, со счета мобильного телефона или через крупнейшую сеть QIWI Терминалов. Оплачивать услуги стало проще.'}, {'key': 'ceo_title', 'value': 'Пополнить QIWI Кошелек: с банковской карты, с баланса телефона, через QIWI Кошелек'}, {'key': 'is_spa_form_available', 'value': 'true'}]}, 'source': {'id': 7, 'shortName': 'QIWI Кошелек', 'longName': 'QIWI Кошелек', 'logoUrl': None, 'description': None, 'keys': 'мобильный кошелек, кошелек, перевести деньги, личный кабинет, отправить деньги, перевод между пользователями', 'siteUrl': None, 'extras': []}, 'comment': '#3496378#', 'currencyRate': 1, 'paymentExtras': [], 'features': {'chequeReady': True, 'bankDocumentReady': False, 'regularPaymentEnabled': True, 'bankDocumentAvailable': False, 'repeatPaymentEnabled': True, 'favoritePaymentEnabled': True, 'chatAvailable': True, 'greetingCardAttached': False}, 'serviceExtras': {}, 'view': {'title': 'Перевод на QIWI Кошелек', 'account': '+79295320477'}}], 'nextTxnId': 14552442122, 'nextTxnDate': '2018-12-24T23:28:05+03:00'}
```

Comment: Попробуйте так отправить. И добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: @suit так я и спрашиваю тут, потому json приходит, который пишет о неправильном формате

Comment: Ошибка `Wrong date format`. Строка с датой правильная? А так, попробуйте `next_txn_date` обработать через `quote` (`from urllib.parse import quote`)

Comment: @gil9red добавил Json от первичного запроса

Comment: Наверное, с форматом все нормально... Попробуйте экранировать через `quote`. А лучше передайте ваши параметры через `params`. Пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/Moodle_examples/search_current_user.py#L24 Там нужно будет словарь отдать

Comment: @gil9red вроде заработало. А в чем проблема была? Невидимые символы? Чтобы я знал и не совершал ошибок таких. Отметьте ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина проблемы в том, что у параметров URL есть формат, разрешенные символы и то каким образом кодировать остальные - [Percent-encoding / URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Например `2018-12-24T23:31:05+03:00` после кодирования станет `2018-12-24T23%3A28%3A05%2B03%3A00`.

Поэтому передавайте параметры через `params`:

```
next_url = root_url + "payment-history/v2/persons/" + login + "/payments"
params = {
    'rows': 1,
    'nextTxnId': next_txn_id,
    'nextTxnDate': next_txn_date,
}
```

json_text = requests.get(next_url, params=params, headers=self.header).json()

`Requests` достаточно умный, чтобы самостоятельно правильно составить итоговый `URL` с параметрами.

---

Либо вручную делайте кодирование через `urllib.parse.quote`.

Пример для `next_txn_date`:

```
from urllib.parse import quote

...

next_url = root_url + "payment-history/v2/persons/" + login + "/payments?rows=1&nextTxnId=" + str(next_txn_id) +"&nextTxnDate=" + quote(next_txn_date)
```

Comment: @danilshik, этого хватит? :)

Comment: спасибо большое.